# FOR LOOP script not running

Tags: oracle, loops, for-loop, plsql, toad

I'm trying to execute a query in Oracle where the input would be a date range and then the query would be executed by how many days there is between the two dates, with the input date also being used as a parameter in the query. I.e., If my input date range would be May 28 - 31, the query would then be executed four times (May 28, 29, 30, 31), and then return the result set of each date in the date range, and then combine all the result sets into one big result set. I'm trying to do this with a `FOR LOOP`. so far I have this:

```
DECLARE

Bus_Date_1 date := '28-MAY-2013';
Bus_Date_2 date := '31-MAY-2013';
Date_Iter date;
Date_Diff integer;

BEGIN

Date_Diff := (Bus_Date_2 - Bus_Date_1) + 1;    

Date_Iter := Bus_Date_1;

FOR SL_Ctr in 1 .. Date_Diff
LOOP
select *
    from (
        select
            cdav.bank_id,
            ent.bank_desc Bank_Description,
            cdav.sol_id,
            sol.sol_desc SOL_Description,
            cdav.gl_sub_head_code GLSH_Code,
            decode(cdav.gl_sub_head_code,
                '10301',1,
                '10403',2, '60403',2, '10501',2, '60501',2, '10502',2, 
                '10503',2, '10504',2, '10505',2, '10507',2, '10509',2, 
                '60509',2, '10511',2, '10518',2, '60518',2, '10523',2, 
                '60523',2, '10551',2, '10552',2, '10553',2, '10554',2, 
                '10555',2, '10557',2, '10559',2, '10561',2, '10568',2, 
                '10573',2,
                '12336',3, '62336',3, '10401',3, '60402',3, 4 ) GLSH_SET ,
            gsh.gl_sub_head_desc GLSH_Name,
            case
                when (cast(substr(cdav.gl_sub_head_code,0,1) as int) >= 1
                    and cast(substr(cdav.gl_sub_head_code,0,1) as int) <= 5)
                then 'R'
                when cast(substr(cdav.gl_sub_head_code,0,1) as int) = 0
                    or (cast(substr(cdav.gl_sub_head_code,0,1) as int) >= 6
                    and cast(substr(cdav.gl_sub_head_code,0,1) as int) <= 9)
                then 'F'
            end book_type,
            gam.foracid account_number,
            gam.acct_name,
            cdav.tran_crncy_code Tran_Currency,
            cdav.value_date,
            cdav.tran_date Transaction_Date,
            cdav.gl_date,
            cdav.tran_particular,
            rank() over(partition by gam.foracid order by eab.eod_date desc) eod_date_rank,
            eab.eod_date,
            case when
                (select tran_date_bal from tbaadm.eab
                    where eab.eod_date = (select max(eab.eod_date) from tbaadm.eab
                        where cdav.acid = eab.acid and eab.eod_date < '28-MAY-2013') -- current date in the LOOP should be here
                    and cdav.acid = eab.acid
                    and cdav.bank_id = eab.bank_id) is not null
                then (select tran_date_bal from tbaadm.eab
                    where eab.eod_date = (select max(eab.eod_date) from tbaadm.eab
                        where cdav.acid = eab.acid and eab.eod_date < '28-MAY-2013') -- current date in the LOOP should be her
                    and cdav.acid = eab.acid
                    and cdav.bank_id = eab.bank_id)
                else 0
            end beg_tran_date_bal,
            (select tran_date_bal from tbaadm.eab eab
                where eod_date = (select max(eab.eod_date) from tbaadm.eab eab
                    where cdav.acid = eab.acid and eab.eod_date <= '28-MAY-2013') -- current date in the LOOP should be her
                and cdav.acid = eab.acid
                and cdav.bank_id = eab.bank_id) end_tran_date_bal,
            ott.ref_num OAP_Ref_No,
            trim(cdav.tran_id) Transaction_ID,
            --cdav.dth_init_sol_id Initiating_SOL_ID,
            'PCC_Code',
            cdav.tran_rmks Tran_Remarks,
            case
                when (cdav.part_tran_type = 'D')
                then (cdav.tran_amt)
            end dr_amount,
            case
                when (cdav.part_tran_type = 'C')
                then (cdav.tran_amt)
            end cr_amount

        from tbaadm.ctd_dtd_acli_view cdav
            left outer join tbaadm.gam
                on cdav.bank_id = gam.bank_id and cdav.acid = gam.acid
            left outer join tbaadm.gsh
                on gam.bank_id = gsh.bank_id and gam.sol_id = gsh.sol_id
                and gam.gl_sub_head_code = gsh.gl_sub_head_code
                and gam.acct_crncy_code = gsh.crncy_code
            left outer join tbaadm.sol
                on cdav.bank_id = sol.bank_id and cdav.sol_id = sol.sol_id
            left outer join tbaadm.eab
                on gam.bank_id = eab.bank_id and gam.acid = eab.acid
            left outer join tbaadm.cnc
                on gam.bank_id = cnc.bank_id and gam.acct_crncy_code = cnc.crncy_code
            left outer join crmuser.end ent
                on cdav.bank_id = ent.bank_id
            left outer join tbaadm.gct
                on cdav.bank_id = gct.bank_id
            left outer join tbaadm.ott
                on cdav.tran_id = ott.tran_id and cdav.tran_date = ott.tran_date
                and cdav.part_tran_srl_num = ott.part_tran_srl_num
                and cdav.bank_id = ott.bank_id and cdav.acid = ott.acid

        where
            gam.acct_ownership = 'O'
            and cdav.bank_id = 'CBC01'
            and cdav.gl_date = '28-MAY-2013' -- current date in the LOOP should be her
            and (gam.gl_sub_head_code in ('10301','10403','60403',
                '10501','60501','10502','10503','10504','10505',
                '10507','10509','60509','10511','10518','60518',
                '10523','60523','10551','10552','10553','10554',
                '10555','10557','10559','10561','10568','10573',
                '12336','62336','10401','60402')
                or gam.acct_classification_flg in ('I','E')
                )
            and trim(cdav.del_flg) in ('N', null)
            and trim(gam.del_flg) in ('N', null)
            and trim(gsh.del_flg) in ('N', null)
            and trim(sol.del_flg) in ('N', null)
            and trim(cnc.del_flg) in ('N', null)
            and trim(gct.del_flg) in ('N', null)
    )

where
    eod_date_rank = 1
    and GLSH_SET = 1

order by
    bank_id,
    sol_id,
    tran_currency,
    glsh_code,
    book_type desc,
    account_number,
    transaction_date;

EXIT WHEN SL_Ctr > Date_Diff;

END LOOP;  
END;
```

whenever I run it, Toad keeps throwing an error, point to the `END LOOP` line at the bottom, saying this:

**PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
   ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
   null pragma raise return select update while with
    
    << continue close current delete fetch lock
   insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall
   merge pipe purge**

I know I still need to add something to the code, but I can't figure out what it is. And I am also aware that the code is incomplete in some areas, because there are still hard-coded stuff in the query itself. Right now, I just want to get the code working into displaying data with the hard-coded stuff.

Any help would be appreciated, and feel free to ask if you need more info regarding the query.

Comment: Comment out the EXIT WHEN SL_Ctr > Date_Diff; line. It's not needed in FOR loop.

Comment: @AsfakulIslam I removed it, I still get the same error.

Comment: Why would you voluntarily execute this statement four times, when one time for all dates at once, will do?

Comment: @RobvanWijk because there's a part in the query which complicates thing. That is, getting the `beg_tran_date_bal` and `end_tran_date_bal`. Trust me, everyone I've asked suggested that I use `BETWEEN-AND`, and I tell them back that it's not appropriate for this particular query.

Comment: I see what you mean. There are few issues with this code. You assign strings to date variables, the EXIT statement is superfluous and you are selecting multiple times from the EAB table. Why not start over and begin with the question what data you need from which tables? You'll likely get a better answer this way.

Answer (score 1):

you wrote:

```
FOR SL_Ctr in 1 .. Date_Diff
LOOP
select *
    from (
      big select
    )

where
    eod_date_rank = 1
    and GLSH_SET = 1

order by
    bank_id,
    sol_id,
    tran_currency,
    glsh_code,
    book_type desc,
    account_number,
    transaction_date;

EXIT WHEN SL_Ctr > Date_Diff;

END LOOP;
END;
```

In pl/sql you can not use SQL this way, you need to select into variables or use something like a cursor for select to use it as an implicit cursor. Change the select inside the loop to assign the result to a variable.

See  [DEVELOPER: PL/SQL Practices On BULK COLLECT](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-mar/o28plsql-095155.html)

an other way of writing could be:

```
FOR SL_Ctr in 1 .. Date_Diff
LOOP
   for i in (
              select *
                from (
                        big select
                     )

where
    eod_date_rank = 1
    and GLSH_SET = 1

order by
    bank_id,
    sol_id,
    tran_currency,
    glsh_code,
    book_type desc,
    account_number,
    transaction_date
)
   loop
      dbms_output.put(line (i.bank_id||' '||i.bank_description);
   end loop;

EXIT WHEN SL_Ctr > Date_Diff;

END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: how would you suggest I do it? And, after assigning the result to a variable, how do I display the result that is now in the variable?